# Why is Penrose's diagrammatic notation for tensor operations not widely used?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, notation

Strictly speaking this is a mathematics question rather than a physics question, but since it is about a way of dealing with tensor bundles that is very remote from what is done in math, and very close to what is common in physics, I think it belongs here.

In [The Road to Reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_to_Reality), Penrose describes a diagrammatic approach to tensor calculations, presumably thought up by himself, that seems to be very useful. In it, a tensor of type $\binom pq$ is represented as an arbitrary shape with $p$ legs on top, and $q$ at the bottom. Contractions of tensors on indices are represented by connections between legs, making the resulting type very clear. As an example, take this image from the book:

[image]

Symmetrizations and antisymmetrizations are indicated by a straight or a wiggly line crossing the indices being (anti)symmetrized over. Exterior products, duals, etc. also come out neatly, see the book for more examples.

This seems to be a very intuitive and error-resistant bookkeeping device. Nevertheless, it doesn't seem to be very widely used.

Does anyone have experience using this notation in tensor calculations? Are they not as useful as they seem? Are they actually widely used and is it just that it is hard to typeset, so that they don't usually show up in a paper?

Comment: Before this gets more votes for being primarily opinion-based: I am not so much interested on whether you like the notation or not, but more in what are the strengths and weaknesses (since it doesn't seem to be widely used, there may be some hidden weaknesses, hence the title).

Comment: For having used it : it's terrible.

Comment: @Slereah haha! Could you elaborate? Is it easy to drive false results? Is it overly convoluted?

Comment: It's all fine and good when you have maybe two indices but then try to keep things reasonable with four when you have to keep track of index position, for instance in symmetrization. It's like a plate of spaghettis.

Comment: Although I cannot answer the “Why” question, you might be interested in the book Group Theory by Cvitanovic which uses these diagrams extensively to derive standard results in the classification of Lie algebras. It is also freely available online.

Comment: It's isomorphic to abstract index notation. Abstract index notation can be typed in LaTeX, but "birdtracks" notation can't.

Comment: @BenCrowell I thought that might have to do with it, but if it would be really useful and popular, someone would likely have made a package, like for Feynman diagrams, quantum circuits and Wick contractions

Comment: @doetoe: But the fact that it's isomorphic to abstract index notation basically means that it's *not* useful. To replace a notation that has been in use for 50 years, a new notation would have to be *better* in some way.

Answer (score 3):

A similar notation is very convenient for graphical reasoning about [tensor network states and algorithms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00006). In particular, one draws arbitrarily shaped blobs to represent the tensors, with legs pointing downward (upward) to represent indices acting on the (dual) vector space of interest, such that contractions are represented by joining legs together. As far as I am aware, this notation is pretty much universally used in the various (theoretical) fields that make use of tensor networks (i.e. condensed-matter physics, quantum optics, quantum information & computation...). It is useful for avoiding tedious index gymnastics, especially when dealing with long strings of contracted tensors.

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting! So it looks like it *is* commonly used after all, only not so much in Penrose's own fields